# match columns and keep all duplicated elements in a data frame column [R]

Tags: r, duplicates, string-matching, textmatching

I have two data frames; DF1 has 3 columns and DF2 has one column.DF1 has all elements contained in DF2 but then most of them are duplicated as shown below.

```
DF1=
***freetext***,         ***specific***,    ***ICDcode*** 

Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C   Hepatitis A       B15
Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C   Hepatitis B       B16
Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C   Hepatitis C       B17.1
Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C   Jaundice          R17
lobar Pneumonia           Lobar pneumonia   J18.1
Lobar Pneumonia ,scabies  Lobar pneumonia   J18.1
scabiess                  scabies            G10     

DF2=          
Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C  
scabiess                            
Lobar Pneumonia ,scabies
lobar Pneumonia
```

I wish to have a match between the two data frames such that whenever a match occurs there should be a resultant data frame taking the form of a DF1.for example *Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C* should appear 4 times instead of appearing once in a column. In other words duplicates should be maintained as shown below ;

```
Resultant data frame should appear like this.

    column1                  column2             column3
Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C   Hepatitis A       B15
Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C   Hepatitis B       B16
Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C   Hepatitis C       B17.1
Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C   Jaundice          R17
```

so,how am i supposed to loop through DF2 to find a match in DF1(first column) and then produce a data frame of matches with all other corresponding rows as shown above?

here is my script but it doesn't seem to produce my desired results

```
   newMatches<- data.frame()
for(i 1:nrow(DF1){ for(j in 1:nrow(DF2[,1]{grep(j, i, ignore.case=F, value=T)->newMatches}} 
#it doesn't produce other columns of DF1
```

any help and or suggestion may be very much appreciated.am slightly novice in R

Comment: Could you expand on what it is you want.  I know you have three upvotes, but I am confused as to exactly what you want.  Everything in DF2 matches at least one row in DF1, or so it seems to me.

Comment: @MarkMiller I want a new data frame where the first column contains all matches of DF1 and DF2(regardless of the duplicates); for example Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C appears once in DF2 but in DF1 they have been split accordingly into specific diagnosis as shown in column2. so am looking for a prudent way to loop in DF2 such that the first match of Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C should have rows of col1 and col2,second match of it should also have its corresponding rows of col1 and col2 in the new data frame..all the way until all matches of Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C have been exhausted.then apply to all

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to filter the rows of DF1, keeping only the ones for which the first column exists in DF2. Is that right? The easiest way to achieve this would be

```
DF1[DF1[, 1] %in% DF2[, 1], ]
```

**Edit**

Here is the full code to reproduce the example:

```
DF1 <- structure(list(
    freetext = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
        .Label = c("Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C", "lobar Pneumonia", 
        "Lobar Pneumonia ,scabies", "scabiess"), class = "factor"),
    specific = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L),  
        .Label = c("Hepatitis A", "Hepatitis B", "Hepatitis C", "Jaundice",
        "Lobar pneumonia", "scabies"), class = "factor"), 
    ICDcode = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L), 
        .Label = c("B15", "B16", "B17.1", "G10", "J18.1", "R17"),
        class = "factor")),
   .Names = c("freetext", "specific", "ICDcode"),
   row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

DF2 <- structure(list(
    freetext = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), 
        .Label = c("Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C", 
         "lobar Pneumonia", "Lobar Pneumonia ,scabies", "scabiess"),
         class = "factor")),
    .Names = "freetext", row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

result <- DF1[DF1[, 1] %in% DF2[, 1], ]
```

Printing `result` gives the following output

```
                  freetext        specific ICDcode
1  Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C     Hepatitis A     B15
2  Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C     Hepatitis B     B16
3  Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C     Hepatitis C   B17.1
4  Jaundice,hepatitisA,B,C        Jaundice     R17
5          lobar Pneumonia Lobar pneumonia   J18.1
6 Lobar Pneumonia ,scabies Lobar pneumonia   J18.1
7                 scabiess         scabies     G10
```

Comment: that suggestion is valuable thanks,but the tricky part here is how to assign each match a unique value as it is appearing in column2.

Comment: @Smock Isn't that unique value already present in DF1? Why does the second column need to be modified? To improve the answer, could you let me know, When you run the suggested command above, how does the output differ from what you want to achieve? When I ran it I got the same result as the "Resultant" data frame you have shown in the original post.

Comment: your command only takes care of the matches between DF1 and DF2 but it doesn't assign the respective values that are found in ***specific*** and  ***ICDcode***  columns shown above in DF1.i would like to have in each row of a match, values of *specific* as well as *ICDcode* as shown in the "ResultantDataFrame"

Comment: @Smock My command does return the other rows as well. Have you tried running it? When you call, for example, DF1[1, ] this returns the 1st row and _all_ the columns in DF1. This is a basic operation on a data frame which you need to familiarise yourself with. I suggest looking at this post, which explains this and more advanced operations very clearly http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html.

Comment: kindly have a look at DF1 onec again.it has three columns ***freetext***,         ***specific***,    ***ICDcode*** .Have tried your command  but its outputting the first column only.please sort me out

Comment: @Smock OK, you may have mistyped my command. Let me update the answer with definition of your data frames as well as the final output. Then you can copy-paste it in your R console and see it works.

Comment: thanx for that elaborate command..am trying to figure out how to script a function that should give a similar output when called on the entire large data(9000 rows)but am stack.could you kindly write a command which is a  function form that can give out  result as the one you have just provided